# Typo3: Repository->findAll() returns only one entry

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have created an extbase extension, using the extension builder.
But when i call findAll() it returns the first row of the mapped table, but again and again. The number of results is correct but all of them are only the first row.

Mapping:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            Vendor\ExtName\Domain\Model\Word {
                mapping {
                    tableName = table_name
                    columns {
                        id.mapOnProperty = id
                        string.mapOnProperty = string
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

listAction():

```
public function listAction() {
    $words = $this->objRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('obj', $objects);
}
```

Comment: Does your table have a uid? otherwise you might want to map uid to id.

Comment: Also, I guess you should assign $words and not $objects to your view.